# ASP.NET MVC + AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a an ASP.NET MVC 5 application with AngularJS.

Some pages requires data from server, which I load using $http provider. But it has a big delay while it is waiting for an answer. For example, I return page from the server, on this page I have Foo Angular controller which firstly makes GET request to server and then my data is parsed into table. While this request is performing I can see template html which then results in normal table.

I found that most solutions uses Angular Routing, but in my case it is not a good way, because it is not really a SPA.

I tried [this](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/10/22/asynchronously-bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data) solution, but also without any real good results.

So, is it possible to load data from the server when my controller starts without using Angular Routing?

**UPDATE**

Here are screens which can show the problem.

When the main page is loaded I see this:

[image]

Then, after few some time I can see the resulting page with angular processing:

[image]

Original request which performs at this time:

[image]

The problem is next: is it possible to not show table layout (first screen) while angular retrieve data from server?

Comment: Angular Routing is not about loading data - it is about showing different views of you SPA app. You load data exactly as you probably do - with `$http`. If your question is about the long delay - there is not enough information in the question to answer this. Look into the network traffic in Chrome dev tools - perhaps it takes a long time for the server to reply. Also, perhaps you have lots of data and takes time render... In other, there is not nearly enough information in the question.

Comment: The first page is shown, not while data is loaded (unless you are preventing angular from bootstrapping), but while angular loads. The answer below about `ng-cloak` should address it

Comment: Thank you, `ng-cloak` is my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has a built in directive meant to handle this situation, [ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak#!/).

> The `ngCloak` directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

Just ensure that angular.js is loaded in the head of the document, and add the `ng-cloak` directive to any HTML elements you are having issue with:

```
<div ng-cloak>{{ 'hello' }}</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Claies. This works great for me. Its awesome

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation on Bootstrapping: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap

This basic set up is all you would need.

```
<div ng-controller="WelcomeController">
  {{greeting}}
</div>
```

Then in your controller make your service call.

```
var app = angular.module('demo', [])
.controller('WelcomeController', function($scope, $http) {
      $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'yoururl.com'
      }).success(function(response){
           $scope.welcome = response;
      });
});
 angular.bootstrap(document, ['demo']);
```

Alternatively, if you're not building a SPA it may be a better option to just use jQuery's AJAX methods.